# Sleuth does not include ParentSpan in b3 single header for message to RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I've recently migrated from Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR2 to Hoxton.SR9, and am using Spring Sleuth to trace incoming REST calls to my Spring Boot app that trigger messages that ultimately arrive in RabbitMQ.

Obviously one of the key differences in Spring Sleuth between those two versions is that, instead of sending 3 separate message headers for trace, span and parentSpan, now only one `b3` header is sent of the form `{trace}-{span}-{sample}-{parentSpan}` with the last two components optional.

The thing that is puzzling me is that the b3 header on the message arriving in RabbitMQ never seems to have a parentSpan component. e.g. the sequence goes something like this:

1. Within app REST controller:              traceId=T, spanId=S1, parentSpanId=S0
2. Prior to sending event from within app:  traceId=T, spanId=S2, parentSpanId=S1
3. Message header on RabbitMQ queue:        b3=T-S2-1

In other words the message header has the right trace, but *shares* the span of the sending event context in the app and has **no** parentSpan.

Is this expected? I feel sure that with previous versions of Sleuth I would have seen a new spanId in the message header and a parentSpan that was equal to the span in the sending event context.

Have I misunderstood what is going on, or (if what I expect is sensible) is there a way to change this default behaviour.

I have the following explicit sleuth property settings:

```
spring.sleuth.enabled=true
spring.messaging.enabled=true
spring.supportsJoin=false
```

(NB: I tried the same with supportsJoin defaulted, but it didn't seem to make any difference to the lack of parentSpanId).

**Debugging Information**

This is what I have been able to determine from stepping through the debugger:

1. We pass a `GenericMessage` into `AbstractMessageChannel.send()`.
2. Eventually the message gets passed into `TracingChannelInterceptor.preSend()`
3. The `TracingChannelInterceptor` is configured with a `DeferredInjector` for which `setter` is an instance of `MessageHeaderPropagation` and `injectorFactory` has a `producerInjectorFunction=SINGLE_NO_PARENT`.
4. The `TracingChannelInterceptor.preSend()` method calls `DeferredInjector.inject(span.context(), headers)`, which results in the SINGLE_NO_PARENT injector adding a `b3` header of the form `{traceId}-{spanId}-1` to the outgoing message.

So the absence of a parentSpanId seems to originate in the fact that the TracingChannelInterceptor.injector is a DeferredInjector whose producer injector is SINGLE_NO_PARENT.

**Custom Configuration**

Registering the following bean to override the default propagation settings changes the behaviour to:

1. Within app REST controller:              traceId=T, spanId=S1, parentSpanId=S0
2. Prior to sending event from within app:  traceId=T, spanId=S2, parentSpanId=S1
3. Message header on RabbitMQ queue:        b3=T-S2-1-S1

But I wonder why it's necessary to do this?

```
@Configuration
public class B3Configuration {
  @Bean
  Propagation.Factory customPropagationFactory() {
    return B3Propagation.newFactoryBuilder()
        .injectFormat(B3Propagation.Format.SINGLE)
        .injectFormat(Span.Kind.CLIENT, B3Propagation.Format.SINGLE)
        .injectFormat(Span.Kind.CONSUMER, B3Propagation.Format.SINGLE)
        .injectFormat(Span.Kind.PRODUCER, B3Propagation.Format.SINGLE)
        .build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a sample project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Hi Jonatan - I don't have something right now but could probably put together something simple if that would help. It's a pretty vanilla Spring Boot setup with Spring Boot 2.3.7 and Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR9.

Comment: I'm away from my source code at the moment but I did try debugging this within my spring boot app, and it got to a point where it was using Format.SINGLE_NO_PARENT rather than FORMAT.SINGLE in the context of an interceptor on an outgoing Spring Message. Sorry I can't be more specific right now.

Comment: @JonatanIvanov I've added some debugging information to the original question which I hope helps - let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: @JonatanIvanov the "issue" (if it is an issue) appears to be fixed by registering the bean I've included in the question text.  But I'm suprised I have to do this to make it work this way.

Comment: The debugging information you added adds value to the question but it lacks a few things that are necessary to properly troubleshoot your issue. In order to do that, a sample project would be really useful, it contains way more info and makes the issue reproducible. 

If you create one, please add a docker-compose file to be able to start RabbitMQ locally, e.g.: https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/local-services/blob/main/rabbit/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Hi @JonatanIvanov thanks for your reply; I will put something together in early Jan after the holidays. I don't think it will be necessary to involve Rabbit as it's easy to reproduce in a test case with mocks - the issue lies purely on the message sender side.

Comment: @JonatanIvanov - I have created a simple Spring Boot project in bitbucket that includes a unit test demonstrating the issue. Just git clone from https://wabrit@bitbucket.org/wabrit/sleuthms.git

Answer (score 1):

It seems the default `B3Propagation.Format` was changed, you can see the current one in [`TraceBaggageConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/97b99bf9e30f312c56971d5a16e177336a8c7f78/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceBaggageConfiguration.java#L79-L82):

```java
// Note: Versions <2.2.3 use injectFormat(MULTI) for non-remote (ex spring-messaging)
// See #1643
static final Propagation.Factory B3_FACTORY = B3Propagation.newFactoryBuilder()
        .injectFormat(B3Propagation.Format.SINGLE_NO_PARENT).build();
```

You can follow the details and the changes were made in  [spring-cloud-sleuth#1643](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1643).

If you want to change the bahavior, I would recommend creating a `BaggagePropagation.FactoryBuilder` instead of a `Propagation.Factory` since when Sleuth autoconfigures the `Propagation.Factory`, it does much more, see in [`TraceBaggageConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/97b99bf9e30f312c56971d5a16e177336a8c7f78/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceBaggageConfiguration.java#L126-L187).

E.g.:

```java
@Bean
BaggagePropagation.FactoryBuilder baggagePropagationFactoryBuilder() {
  return BaggagePropagation.newFactoryBuilder(
          B3Propagation.newFactoryBuilder()
                  .injectFormat(B3Propagation.Format.SINGLE)
                  .build()
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this @JonatanIvanov, and for the helpful suggestion about using `BaggagePropagation.newFactoryBuilder`.

I looked through the issue link but am unsure as to the conclusion - is this default behaviour (using SINGLE_NO_PARENT) correct? The outcome seems odd to me.